# efficient null evaluation in java

Tags: java

i got the following method

```
public Person findByAdd(String add) {
    try {
        final String queryString = "select p from Destinations p where p.address = :add";
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("add", add);
        return (Person) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    }
}
```

which throws null-pointer exception if Person object does not exist,and i want to do something like this

```
if(person.getAdd !=null){
   system.out.println ("address exist");    
}
else
{
system.out.println ("please enter address ");   
}
```

but this throws an exception if person doesn't exist,how can i efficiently evaluate the if person is null

Comment: How about `person == null`? I don't know why you even mention "efficient" here.

Comment: Also:  `} catch (RuntimeException re) { throw re; }` is pretty much a no-op, you can leave that out as well.

Comment: Why are you catching `RuntimeException`? You should catch `NoResultException`.

Comment: Google it first.. Follow some forum.. Read It.. Then try, try, try. It will works....

Answer (score 5):

```
if (person != null && person.getAdd() != null)
   System.out.println ("address exist");    
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the correction! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getSingleResult()` if you want to return a `null` value. Use this:

```
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Person.class);
List<Person> list = query.getResultList();
if (list.isEmpty()){
    return null;
}
return list.get(0);
//or inlined: return list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0);
```

Comment: `getSingleResult` will also work, provided OP caught `NoResultException`, instead of `RuntimeException`. Using `getResultList` is really not required here. And I won't use it.

Comment: It feels cleaner than catching an exception. It could also be inlined to return list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0);

Comment: @RohitJain So don't use it. The world is full of options. I prefer not to use exception handling as flow control.

Comment: @RohitJain http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl